# How to launch 3+ instances of freerdp for 3 windows VMs from single centos

Tags: shell-script, centos, freerdp, xfreerdp, multiple-machines

I have 3 or more windows machines, those I can connect from centos individually using below command

```
xfreerdp /u:username /p:password /v:hostname
```

but what I want is to connect them in parallel, using some shell script like -

```
#!/bin/bash

xfreerdp /u:username /p:password /v:host1 &
xfreerdp /u:username /p:password /v:host2 &
xfreerdp /u:username /p:password /v:host3
wait
```

Try1 : and received the below error, and also it has launched the only single rdp connection.

> rdp_set_error_info:freerdp_set_last_error_ex
> ERRINFO_DISCONNECTED_BY_OTHER_CONNECTION [0x00010005]

Tyr2 : after the above attempt I tried using separate tabs of terminal to start the new RDP session for new VM still it throws same error.

Please suggest if any other ways of doing rdp connection in parallel.

**Note:** I don't have multimonitors to my system. I want this sessions on single system for different VM's

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer you sought during a bit of research I was doing for myself and I figured I'd circle back to throw you an answer...

```
xfreerdp /sec:tls /u:azuread\user@domain.org /v:$IPaddress +clipboard /h:900 /w:1600 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This will launch the window then release the terminal and you can add this line 3 times into a `.sh` file to launch all 3 at once, just update the `/v:` address on each line. Remember to add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the `.sh` file and `chmod +x file.sh` to let it execute.

Comment: I did this using 1.) threading. it was simpler, 2.) you can launch the gnome terminal and then fire the `xfreerdp` command to it to work all this 3 commands in parallel, first one was good since it was opening only 3 windows 2nd one will open 3 gnome terminals and 3 `xfreerdp` windows